# PL/pgSQL package manager for Postgres libraries

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am a software engineer studying PostgreSQL.
PostgreSQL supports lots of languages (e.g. plpgsql).
I don't see an easy way to install storied procedures.
Is there some sort of `pip` or `npm` analog?
I found abandoned `pex` tool.

PostgreSQL can define functions programmatically.
So it must be trivial to write a function as `pg_install_library` taking a link to github repo - pulling files with plpgsql functions, types, then checking declared functions in db and if function is missing or hash code is different then evals new version to declare/redeclare.

```
# select pg_install_library('http://github.com/hello/world');
```

Comment: PL/SQL is only used by Oracle. It's not available in (standard/plain) Postgres. To "install" a stored procedure, you run a `create procedure` statement. I think the concept you are looking for is provided through extensions in Postgres.

Comment: postgres extension is hard to install. I have just access to psql session.

Comment: `create extension` can be used in `psql`  - that doesn't really qualify as "hard" to me. But if you don't want to package your procedures into an extension, then just put them in SQL scripts and run those scripts. You might want to use a schema migration tool like Liquibase to automate that

Comment: `create extension` expects local files at specific location to be ready to read. In cloud setup it is not feasible. The feature is not high level enough. Transitive dependencies are not handled, right?

Comment: You typically don't have a transitive dependencies for procedures. You don't include a gazillion of libraries as you do with npm. In fact you typically don't include any "libraries" in stored procedures or functions. You _might_ have some utility functions or procedures that are re-used in others. But that is a simply matter of creating them in the right order. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? Which libraries do you intend to include here?

Comment: I don't have lot of code. Just a few procedures, but I don't want to copy-past them manually across multiple DB instances (they are independent - no replication). It is sad to know that there is no such thing because it is very cool and productivity multiplier. There is no transitive deps because env is hampered by laking package manager just like with C language. Look at Java, Perl, Python, JS they all thrive through sharing code.

Comment: If you need to deploy your procedures and functions to multiple instances, use a schema migration tool. Running the DDL for a procedure isn't really that much different than running a DDL to create or alter a table. You can't compare a few hundred lines of (stand alone) code for procedures with hundreds of thousands of lines of Java code that uses hundreds of external libraries

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent would be a PostgreSQL [extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html). Extensions have support for versioning and dependencies to other extensions.

Sure, you need shell access to the database machine to install the extension, just like with `pip` and other package managers.